# regex for a special pattern of phone number extension

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I need a reg-ex for a pattern in a text box where pattern be as follow :

**+1245** here first always should be a plus sign (+) and rest of all 4 should be digits (0 to 9)

I have used the other available reg-ex on google but they are mostly for the complete phone number not for extension .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^[+][0-9]{4}.*$
```

This will match a leading plus followed by exactly four digits, which can also be followed by anything else.

Comment: compile time error unrecognised escape sequence error .

Comment: @rahularyansharma I apologize for the error, but you did not initially tell us which language you were using.  It should run fine now.

Comment: ohhh ,, yes its my mistake , after editing i included c# and asp.net mvc . will check and let you know . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your entire string is as described, use this pattern:

```
^\+\d{4}$
```

`^` means the beginning of the string 
`\+` means + (escape the + sign) 
`\d{4}` means exactly 4 digits 
`$` means the end of the string